# Got error of no OpenSSL crypto library found under win10

Tags: perl

I am working on active state perl under win10.

In my project, I need package Filter::Crypto::Decrypt, so I install it by command:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Filter::Crypto::Decrypt
```

wait a while, I was asked:

```
Where is your OpenSSL?
```

Then I download a OpenSSL 1.1.1c installer from website slproweb.com and install it to c:\OpenSSL-Win64. Finally I copy this installation path and paste it into position after the question in console, press the ENTER key. Then I get following error:

```
No OpenSSL crypto library found at Makefile.PL line 66
```

But before this error message, I see information:

```
Found include directory ....... c:\OpenSSL-Win64\include

Found OpenSSL version ....... 1.1.1c
```

which means version and include folder of OpenSSL are found and recognized.

thanks

Comment: You should install `Crypt::SSLeay` beforehand

Comment: Can you please show the full log?

Comment: how to get the log?

Comment: when I install Crypt::SSLeay, I get error: `openssl-version.c:2:30:fatal error openssl/opensslv.h no such file or directory compilation terminated`

Comment: `perl -MCPAN -e shell` can be shortened to just `cpan`.

Comment: yes. and then install cpanm. but it is difficult to install package in my post under windows. many dependencies problems. ppm is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

ppm saved me. use ppm to install modules for active state perl under windows.